# Using scandir on array of directories

Tags: php

I would like to pass in an array that contains a list of directories to scan. I want to iterate over each directory and push its content into another array that I will print out, but for some reason my code is not working. The directories exist and the path is correct. I think it has something to do with how I'm using foreach.

These are the errors I'm getting:

> Notice: Undefined index: C:\Users\john\Desktop\files\images\ in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 6
>
> Warning: scandir(): Directory name cannot be empty in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 6

This is the code:

```
function test($dir = []) {
    foreach($dir as $bar) {
        $list = [];
        array_push($list, scandir($dir[$bar]));
    }

    print_r($list);
}

test(["C:\Users\john\Desktop\files\images\\", "C:\Users\john\Desktop\files\images\autumn\\"]);
```

If anyone can think of a simpler way to do this, please don't hesitate to tell me.

Comment: PHP's `foreach` is not like JavaScript's `for in` statement; `$bar` will be the actual element, not the element's key.

Comment: What does `$dir` look like?

Comment: @TimCooper: Ah okay. But i'm only seeing the content of the second directory. I changed it to `foreach($dir as $bar) { $list = []; array_push($list, scandir($bar)); }` - would that be correct?

Comment: You're resetting `$list` with each directory.  Move `$list` out of the `foreach`.

Comment: You just want to call `scandir($bar)` and append the result to $list using array_merge(). In your current form, you are resetting the content of the list each iteration. Note that if you wanted to iterate over keys and values, there is the `foreach ($array as $key => $value)` syntax, but I don't think there's any need for that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. There are a few changes you need to make though.

```
function test($dir = []) {
    $list = [];
    foreach($dir as $bar) {
        $list[] = scandir($bar);
    }  
    print_r($list);
}
```

As noted by *@BrianPoole* you need to move the `$list` out of the `foreach` loop. By having it in the loop, the array is reset with each iteration, resulting in the final array having one element.

In addition, the `foreach` loop as explained above by *@TimCooper* does not operate the same as in JavaScript. If you really want to access the keys, you can use the following syntax:

```
foreach($dir as $key => $bar)
```

You would then use either `$dir[$key]` or `$bar` to access the directory value.

Finally, `array_push` is an additional function call that in your case is not needed. By simply adding `[]` PHP will push the new value onto the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
function test($dir) {
    // DEFINE LIST OUT SIDE OF LOOP
    $list = array();
    // Run checks
    if(count($dir) > 0) {
        // Loop Through Directory
        foreach($dir as $directory) {
            // Push into list
            array_push($list, array("scanned"=>$directory, "contents" => scandir($directory)));
        }
    }else {
        // If no directories are passed return array with error
        $list = array(
            "error" => 1,
            "message" => "No directories where passed into test()",
        );
    }
    print_r($list);
}
```

This is how I would do it. It provides a couple checks and sets up the data so you can se it a bit more clear.